Unit tests for DynamoDB Queries
I have this method
    public List<T> queryGSI(final String indexName, final String gsiHashKeyName, final String gsiHashKeyValue,
        final String gsiRangeKeyName, final String gsiRangeKeyValue) {
        Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<>();
        eav.put(":gsiHashKey", new AttributeValue().withS(gsiHashKeyValue));
        eav.put(":gsiRangeKey", new AttributeValue().withS(gsiRangeKeyValue));
        DynamoDBQueryExpression<T> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<T>()
            .withIndexName(indexName)
            .withKeyConditionExpression(gsiHashKeyName + " = :gsiHashKey and " + gsiRangeKeyName + " = :gsiRangeKey")
            .withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);
        try {
            return mapper.query(tableClass, queryExpression);
        } catch (final AmazonClientException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to query GSI with hash key and range key", e);
        }
    }

with DynamoDBMapper and TableClass injected.
I have a DDB record class that uses all the annotations. @DynamoDBIndexHashKey @DynamoDBIndexRangeKey etc.
In my test case I did this
@Mock
    private DynamoDBMapper mockMapper;

    @Captor
    ArgumentCaptor<DynamoDBQueryExpression<DDBItem>> expressionArgumentCaptor;

        DDBItem testItem = DDBItem.builder()
            .att1("val1")
            .att2("val2")
            .att3("val3")
            .build();

        when(mockMapper.query(eq(DDBItem.class), any(DynamoDBQueryExpression.class))).thenReturn(
            mock(PaginatedQueryList.class, Mockito.withSettings().defaultAnswer(new ForwardsInvocations(singletonList(testItem)))));

        BaseOperations<DDBItem> baseOperations = new BaseOperations<>(mockMapper, DDBItem.class);
        List<DDBItem> result = baseDynamoDBOperations.queryGSI(
           "IndexName",
            "att1",
            "val1",
            att2,
            "val2"
        );
        
        verify(mockMapper, times(1)).query(eq(DDBItem.class), expressionArgumentCaptor.capture());

        DynamoDBQueryExpression<DDBItem> expression = expressionArgumentCaptor.getValue();

        assertEquals(testItem, result.get(0));

This is throwing null pointer exception at
     when(mockMapper.query(eq(DDBItem.class), any(DynamoDBQueryExpression.class))).thenReturn(
            mock(PaginatedQueryList.class, Mockito.withSettings().defaultAnswer(new ForwardsInvocations(singletonList(testItem)))));

Can somebody help me solve this issue?
